# Extract "values" from VectorUDT sparse vector in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, vector, azure-databricks

I have a pyspark dataframe with 2 vector columns.
When I show the dataframe in my notebook, it prints each vector like this: {"vectorType": "sparse", "length": 262144, "indices": [21641], "values": [1]}

When I print the schema, it shows up as VectorUDT.

I just need the "values" field value as a list or array. How can I save that as a new field?
Doing "vector_field".values doesn't seem to work because pyspark thinks it's a String...

Comment: see [`vector_to_array`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.functions.vector_to_array.html#pyspark-ml-functions-vector-to-array)

Comment: Yes vector_to_array is what I ended up using. @samkart if you want to post an answer with an example of using that, I'll be happy to mark it as the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spark has a builtin ml function for vector-to-array conversion - [`vector_to_array`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.functions.vector_to_array.html#pyspark-ml-functions-vector-to-array). you can simply pass the vector column to get the same as 1D array.

here's an example

```py
from pyspark.ml.linalg import SparseVector, DenseVector
import pyspark.ml.functions as mfunc

data_ls = [
    (SparseVector(3, [(0, 1.0), (2, 2.0)]),), 
    (DenseVector([3.0, 0.0, 1.0]),), 
    (SparseVector(3, [(1, 4.0)]),)
]

spark.createDataFrame(data_ls, ['vec']). \
    withColumn('arr', mfunc.vector_to_array('vec')). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +-------------------+---------------+
# |vec                |arr            |
# +-------------------+---------------+
# |(3,[0,2],[1.0,2.0])|[1.0, 0.0, 2.0]|
# |[3.0,0.0,1.0]      |[3.0, 0.0, 1.0]|
# |(3,[1],[4.0])      |[0.0, 4.0, 0.0]|
# +-------------------+---------------+

# root
#  |-- vec: vector (nullable = true)
#  |-- arr: array (nullable = false)
#  |    |-- element: double (containsNull = false)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried using the below vector values:

```
smpl_data = [(SparseVector(3, {0: 1.0, 2: 2.0}),),
        (DenseVector([3.0, 0.0, 1.0]),),
        (SparseVector(3, {1: 4.0}),)]
dilip_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["vector_field"])
dilip_df.printSchema()
dilip_df.show()
```

[image]

I have defined a function. This function takes a vector as input.
And it will check whether the vector is **SparseVector** or **DenseVector**.
If it is a SparseVector, it converts the values to a list using `vector.values.tolist()`.
If it is a DenseVector, it also converts the values to a list using `vector.values.tolist()`.
If the vector is neither SparseVector nor DenseVector, it returns **None**.
Using `.withColumn` creating a new column **values_list**
The udf function from PySpark is used to register the `extract_values` function as a UDF.
The UDF is assigned to the variable extract_values_udf.
The second argument to the udf function specifies the return type of the UDF, which is `ArrayType(DoubleType()).`
This indicates that the UDF returns an array of double values.

```
def extract_values(vector):
    if isinstance(vector, SparseVector):
        return vector.values.tolist()
    elif isinstance(vector, DenseVector):
        return vector.values.tolist()
    else:
        return None
extract_values_udf = udf(extract_values, ArrayType(DoubleType()))
dilip_df = dilip_df.withColumn("values_list", extract_values_udf("vector_field"))
dilip_df.show(truncate=False)
```

```
+-------------------+---------------+
|vector_field       |values_list    |
+-------------------+---------------+
|(3,[0,2],[1.0,2.0])|[1.0, 2.0]     |
|[3.0,0.0,1.0]      |[3.0, 0.0, 1.0]|
|(3,[1],[4.0])      |[4.0]          |
+-------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Thanks! This works to get the list of non-zero values, but excludes all the 0 values (since those dont show up by default despite having indices listed for them). I ended up getting it to work using vector_to_array.